# Powerbi Dax Filter for selecting all similar rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

wondering if someone can please help me. I have two tables **units** and **unit_versions**.

**units table**

| id | unit_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 3 | 36 |
| 4 | 37 |
| 5 | 38 |

**unit_versions table**

| id | unit_id | first_version_unit_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2 |
| 2 | 35 | 3 |
| 3 | 36 | 2 |
| 4 | 37 | 1 |

I currently have a 1:1 relationship on unit_id between the two tables.

I have a selector where users can select the unit id and then I want another selector to display all the other units from the **unit_versions** table that have the same first_version_unit_id

So if the user selected row 1 (unit_id=30) from the **units** selector, I would see the rows 1 and 3 from **unit_versions** in the second selector, as they both have the first_version_unit_id as 2.

Thankyou for anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In PQ merge *unit_versions* into *units* based on *unit_id*
2. Establish a many:many relationship between the 2 tables based on
   first_version_unit_id
3. Add 2 slicer based on the 2 tables unit_id's and the 2nd slicer behaves as desired

Comment: Ah yes thank you! i had tried a similar solution but was looking the lookupvalue to create that extra column but that created a circular relationship. Your solution to merge works well. Thanks!